# OSGI Bundle resolved state issue

Tags: osgi, aem

One of my OSGI bundles goes into resolved state every now and then without any errors. I have to manually activate it everytime. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you use AEM.. can you give more details about the bundle?

Comment: It is basically used to deal with translation of pages. So, it also helps to add details to a drop down. Everytime the drop down doesn't show the details, we see that the bundle is in resolved state. On activating the bundle, the drop down gets data again.

Comment: what version of AEM is this? there was a bug in 6.1 that did result in situations like this but was fixed in subsequent editions.

Comment: Does it have the immediate=true property in the @Component annotation?